# Multiple separate instances of same version of PHP-FPM with different php.ini (non per-dir settings)

Tags: php, fpm

I have Apache with several vhosts using **PHP-FPM**.

Most of the vhosts use the same version of PHP, 7.4.

My problem is: there are **certain settings** of PHP that **cannot be overridden in .user.ini**. And yet I need those settings to have different values for **different virtualhosts**.

In practice for me it's just one setting: **xdebug.mode**. I need it off for most vhosts, but on for one. Unfortunately, as per xdebug documentation:

> This setting can only be set in php.ini or files like 99-xdebug.ini that are read when a PHP process starts (directly, or through php-fpm), but not in .htaccess and .user.ini files, which are read per-request.

My guess is, if it's possible with phpfpm to have multiple php versions running in parallel, certainly it must be possible to have multiple independent, isolated "instances" of the same version, each with its own global configuration, right? ....right? And have one (or a few) vhost use one of them, while all the other vhosts use the other.

How do I do that?

Comment: I work on Nginx, not Apache, but the PHP should be the same. You should have `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf` (or similar path depending on version and OS) for loading your main FPM config. Inside of that there's usually a directive such as `include=/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/*.conf` which means you can create a site-specific file such as `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/example.conf` with a dedicated socket handler, which I then think you set using `SetHandler` in your Apache conf

Comment: This won't let you enable/disable modules completely (I don't think), but for xdebug you can at least enable it globally and then change the `xdebug.mode` value per site